# clang unicode characters for variable name

Tags: unicode, clang, variable-names

cat test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int à;
}
```

results in:

```
clang++ test.cpp
test.cpp:4:7: error: expected unqualified-id
  int à;
      ^
1 error generated.
```

Now, is there a way to get clang to allow unicode variable names?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it standard C to have Unicode characters inside identifiers?

Comment: `clang++` 3.4 supports this. Since 3.3 (http://llvm.org/releases/3.3/tools/clang/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#major-new-features)

Answer (score 2):

While this is allowed by the standard, Clang does not currently support UCN (universal character name)s in identifiers.

Comment: Are there any other restrictions on the use of Unicode by Clang? e.g., not in comments/strings, ...?

Comment: Clang supports UCNs in comments and strings. Although I'm not sure what the source charset has to be, or what it's converted to.